# Memory Stick Controller is not compatible with this version of Windows

Tags: windows-7, controller, memory-card

I'm getting this error message in the Action Center on Windows 7, and I can't seem to solve it through Windows or through searches on Google:

> RICOH R5C592 PCI-CardBus/IEEE-1394/SD Card/Memory Stick Controller is not compatible with this version of Windows.

Thanks for any help

PS. I wasn't sure if you're allowed to post questions like this, about proprietary software, but I checked the FAQ and it seemed ok.

**Response:**

The URL I am told to visit it [this](http://support.asus.com/download/download.aspx?SLanguage=en-us) but I can't tell which I should choose that I am originally presented with, or what to put in to select, as I am not sure what input it is referring to.

Comment: What brand and model of computer is this?  The manufacturer might have an updated driver for your card reader.

Answer (score 1):

Your only way forward here is to check the manufacturer's website to see if they have release Windows 7 compatible drivers for the device. Otherwise you will either need to remove it, or just ignore the message and simply not use it.

Comment: I have had had *some* success forcing Windows 7 to use older drivers for media card readers, like those made for Vista.

Answer (score 0):

In the link that you provide in your edit, there is a link to "Card Reader Application." I'd say that's a pretty safe bet to try first.